# Eyaml and Puppet

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, puppet

I have keys, certificate and intermediate chain certificate that I need to put into Hiera and using eyaml to encrypt before putting into Hiera on puppet. My question is do I have to encrypt each of the certificates and the key and copy the contents into Hiera. I would like an example if possible. These are wildcard certificate that I purchased from Godaddy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is do I have to encrypt each of the certificates and the key and copy the contents into Hiera.

Does the [documentation](https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml) for eyaml need clarification? To answer your question, yes you do.

For example, to create an encrypted copy of a private key:

```
$ eyaml encrypt -l my_hiera_key_name -f path_to_secret.key
```

This command will produce two differently-formatted outputs suitable for copying straight into your Hiera file. Just choose the one you like the best, and copy/paste it into Hiera.